Documents needed when travelling with an EU spouse across the EU
My husband holds an EU (Irish) passport and I have a UK passport, we have recently been visiting Portugal looking at areas with a view to moving over here up until now we will have stayed for a total of 55 days (over Sept/Nov) - we wish to return for a further 62 days (over Dec/Feb) and are enquiring if any documentation/evidence is required to prove that I am travelling with a EU citizen ensuring I do not break the 90/180 day rule and how I am to confirm this.

In practice I've never been asked for documentation nor have my parents, but the number of occasions on which the issue might even have been raised is already quite small.  A simple statement "this is my husband" should suffice in most cases, but a copy of your marriage certificate can't hurt.  For a residence card application, of course, it will be necessary.  In addition to your marriage certificate, you'll need his Irish passport, or a copy of it if you're not traveling together.

@Traveller This question is not whether this is allowed (the OP knows it is and indicated that in the question) but what specific documents might be necessary to benefit from this right.

@Relaxed The answer to the suggested duplicate covers that.

@Traveller Sure but the question isn't a duplicate.

In practice, you probably won't need anything else than your passports in this case. If your rights are somehow being challenged and you want to make absolutely sure to be prepared, you need to establish three facts. This will in turn tell you what documents might be useful.

Your husband's EU citizenship. The relevant document here is his passport.
That the two of you are married. A marriage certificate or any other document that shows you are married and can be matched to your passports would cover that.
That your husband is also visiting the country you are trying to reach. That's obvious if you are crossing the border together but might need to be documented if you are joining your husband but travelling alone (which is also perfectly fine).

